# Method to provide an efficient callback to ReadFile

Tags: c++, winapi, readfile, hard-drive

In my worker thread I need to have an ability to stop a long file operation upon user input. My current approach is to call `ReadFile` repeatedly on a small buffer and then invoke the callback function after each iteration. Something like this:

```
//Error checks are omitted for brevity

for(;;)
{
    ::ReadFile(hFile, SmallBuffer, nSizeOfSmallBuffer, nBytesRead);

    if(!pfnCallbackProc())
    {
        //Abort
        break;
    }
}

BOOL callbackProc()
{
    return ::WaitForSingleObject(hStopEvent, 0) == WAIT_OBJECT_0;
}
```

This method works. But when I did my benchmark tests to see how much slower it runs against a simple call to:

```
::ReadFile(hFile, FullBuffer, nSizeOfFullBuffer, nBytesRead);
```

the difference is not that much on an SSD (random access disk), but it becomes quite pronounced when I'm reading a large file from a spinning drive. For instance, reading a 4GB file takes about 32 seconds with a single `ReadFile`, and about 46 seconds using my method with a callback above. (I understand that a larger delay happens because of repeated calls to `ReadFile` on a spinning disk.)

So I was wondering if there's a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: As you tagged winapi, have a read of I/O Completion Ports on MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198(v=vs.85).aspx  Also overlapped IO: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686358(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The only way is to lower the amount of iteration of the loop. And one way to do that is to increase the buffer size you read. You simply have to experiment with a number of different buffer-sizes you read, so you get acceptable performance while still be able to fulfill the requirements of your program (like being able to cancel the reading within a short-enough time).

Comment: Get fancy and measure it during your program run (not as design time, but I mean in your actual released application), and tune the size to be as big as possible but still be responsive.

Comment: simply call `CancelIoEx` on file if you want stop read

Comment: What is nSizeOfSmallBuffer

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: In my actual function, the buffer is originally set to `0x1000` bytes. Then it's dynamically adjusted after each read, depending on how long it took to read the previous buffer within the specified delay, which was 200ms in my tests. If the time elapsed to read the buffer is longer than the delay, the buffer size is shrunk by 1/8th of its size. Otherwise, it's increased by 1/8th.

Comment: 4k is a tiny buffer. And your adaptive algorithm sounds a bit iffy. You'd be better reading multiples of sector size. And you'll be flip flopping back and forth around that 200ms decision point.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: 4k is the sector size on NTFS, is it not?

Comment: 4k plus 1/8 isn't a multiple of 4k

Answer (score 4):

Probably the most obvious possibility would be to use `ReadFileEx` to do an overlapped read. Then you can use `CancelIo` to cancel the I/O when/if necessary.

Since this is overlapped, you may be able to call it directly from the parent thread instead of creating a thread dedicated to the I/O. The main requirement is that the calling thread go into an alertable wait state when it's ready to process feedback from the overlapped I/O. In a typical case where the parent thread uses a `GetMessage` loop, you'd change it to use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx` instead. That lets you continue to retrieve messages, but also enters the alertable wait state, so the callback you pass to `ReadFileEx` can be invoked as well.

Comment: really both `ReadFile` and `ReadFileEx` allow asynchronous read. different - `ReadFile` worked with IOCP, when `ReadFileEx` with apc completion only

Comment: @RbMm: Yes, they both support Overlapped I/O. But he asked for efficient too--and at least when I've tested them, ReadFileEx had a fairly significant advantage in that regard. That said, I'll openly admit that my testing didn't cover every possible scenario, nor is it clear exactly how much slow-down he's willing to accept, so an overlapped ReadFile may be sufficient (and as I recall, the code for it is somewhat simpler).

Comment: basically if we want stop (cancel) read operation we can call `CancelIoEx` from another thread too. so we even not need asynchronous io for file. exist different ways, and depended from details one or another can be more effective

Comment: Thank you, both. That sounds reasonable. And how do I get the progress of the file read, is it by calling `GetOverlappedResult` with `bWait` set to FALSE?

Comment: @c00000fd - impossible get progress of *single* file read. `GetOverlappedResult` nothing give you because `IO_STATUS_BLOCK` filled after io complete. if want progress - only many small reads. anyway - are you try read 4gb for example in single buffer ?

Comment: @RbMm: Sure, I can read it all into 4GB single buffer if memory allocation allows.